# What do I put in my Ruby (JRuby) code to break into the debugger?

Tags: ruby, debugging, jruby, break

I'm familiarizing myself with some JRuby code, and I'd like to be able to place a breakpoint in the code and run (as usual) from the command-line, having it break into the debugger when it gets to that point.  Is there something I can put in my code to force JRuby to break into the debugger?

I've tried running `jruby -r debug foo.rb` (instead of the usual `jruby foo.rb`), and then setting a breakpoint with `b bar.py:98`, and then continuing.  But the debugger stops every time there's an exception, and there seem to be a lot of them before it gets to the line of code I'm interested in.  I'd like to be able to put the "break-into-debugger" line(s) in my code and run `jruby foo.rb` and have the first place the debugger stops be at that line.

(i.e. I'm looking for the Ruby/JRuby equivalent of `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` in Python.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) [Ruby IDE](http://netbeans.org/features/ruby/index.html), it has JRuby interpreter and debugging tools embedded and you can debug visually in the IDE directly.
If using an IDE is not an option for you, just install de `debug` gem into your JRuby distro and use it via `debugger` command:

1. Manually download the ruby-debug-base-0.10.3.1-java.gem from [debug-commons](http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=3085)  to a local directory.
2. Install the Gem into your JRuby Gem repository:
   `jruby -S gem install -l ruby-debug-base-0.10.3.1-java.gem`
3. Install ruby-debug gem:
   `jruby -S gem install --ignore-dependencies ruby-debug`

The `debugger` command should work now.

```
# test.rb
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-debug'
debugger
# run like this:
jruby --debug -S rdebug test.rb
```

More information on [Netbeans wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/RubyDebugging), [rdebug wiki](http://debug-commons.rubyforge.org/#jruby-debug) and [JRuby wiki](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/UsingTheJRubyDebugger)

Comment: Netbeans is working nicely for me, with only a tiny bit of configuration required.  Thanks!

Comment: In JRuby 1.5+, all the required gems will be installed by default, so there will be no need to install anything (esp. with non-default command line options). So, debug will work in JRuby 1.5+ out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-debug'
debugger
```

Comment: I got "LoadError: no such file to load -- ruby-debug" — perhaps that doesn't work in JRuby?

Comment: Apparently JRuby doesn't support any gems with non-native Ruby components; Google turned up the following, but I have no idea if it's any good: http://debug-commons.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am using JRuby 1.7.3 (1.9.3p385) on Windows 7.

Contrary to what people say, there does *not* seem to be a version of ruby-debug preinstalled with JRuby.  However, I installed it by running `gem install ruby-debug`.  I start the debugger in my code like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ruby-debug'
debugger
```

You should call the `debugger` method everywhere that you want to have a breakpoint.

I ran the code like this:

```
jruby --debug program.rb
```

The `--debug` option is optional, but without it you get a warning that "tracing (e.g. set_trace_func) will not capture all events without --debug flag".

Another answer on here used the `-S rdebug` option on the command line.  That option is not necessary for debugging and it makes the debugger start at the very beginning of your program.  Just call the `debugger` method to start the debugger when you need it; don't use that option.

Even without the ruby-debug gem, it seems like there is still some kind of basic debugging built in to JRuby via [debug.rb](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/lib/ruby/1.9/debug.rb).  You can simply write `load 'debug.rb'` in a file to start a debugger going.  It prints out some junky messages ("Debug.rb" and "Emacs support available.") but it seems to work.